# Sending byte[] data to an activity without creating a file

Tags: android, android-intent, attachment

I have developed an android application which takes a picture, calls a web services and sends both documents (the picture and web service response) with `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE` intent. This action requires the data to be passed as an `ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>`; Therefore the application stores the data in temporary files and creates two `Uri` objects from these files. The main drawback is that the application cannot delete these temporary files since it is not possible to determine if the called activity handled the data.

Is it possible to send data (`byte[]` data type) with an `ACTION_SEND` or `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE` without creating temporary files?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

of course! 
if suppose you have data in byte [] data,
you can do it like this.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND) ;

i.setType("your mime type here");

i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, data);

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i,"Send this To:"));
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not seem to work. I tried with GMail or Dropbox application which handle ACTION_SEND but according to the stacktrace in the debug monitor both applications are expecting URI as EXTRA_STREAM parameters.